# How can I make one command not need a prefix with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a certain command for my discord.py bot not require a prefix, but I'm not sure how to go about that as the prefix is technically hard-coded into the bot and if I change the main "commands.Bot" and "command_prefix" stuff to an empty string, all of the commands respond to an empty string then the command. Any way I could do this? Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
from random import randint
import itertools
from itertools import cycle

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '')
TOKEN = # redacted
status = cycle(["with hot pizza rolls...", "with these balls!!!", "with a mind.","Minecraft Battle Royale", "ur mum lol", "Muck", "Terraria Battle Grounds", "shitnite", "Stick Fight: The Game", "THE XYLOBONES", "FL Studio",])
#ready, join, and leave events
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    reload_status.start()
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('with hot pizza rolls...'))
    print("baby shitter is online")

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def reload_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} joined a server. Grab the popcorn.')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} went bye bye.')

#commands

#check please
@client.command(aliases=["checkplease","checkpls","chkplease"])
async def chkpls(bepis):
    await bepis.send('You were pinged a total of ' + str(randint(0,69420)) + " times in the past 24 hours.")
    print(f"the bot's ping is {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")

#eight ball
@client.command(aliases=["8ball","eightball","8bll"])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    Ballresponses = ["It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.",
        "Yes definitely.",
        "Yes absolutely.",
        "Reply not certain, try again.",
        "Ask again later.",
        "Can’t really tell you now.",
        "Can’t predict that right now.",
        "I wouldn’t count on it.",
        "You’re outta luck.",
        "My sources say no.",
        "Yeah, uh…..no.",
        "Not a chance."]
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(Ballresponses)}')

#dice roll
@client.command(aliases=["6dice","roll"])
async def dice(bepis):
    await bepis.send(random.choice(["You roll a 6 sided dice. It landed on a ", "The die of 6 sides rolled itself before you could grab it. It landed on a ", "You used to roll the dice. Well, actually, you already rolled it. It landed on a ", "MADRE LAMADA PUTA PUTA DADOS PERRA. ESE HIJO DE PUTA ATERRIZÓ EN UN ", "Thou hand hath thrown thy dice o' six sides. Thou hath landed on thy feet, with thou side facing upwards being a ", "The dice ran away, tripped on a rock, and died. It's last word was ", "Couldn't get enough dice rolls from last bot, eh? Well, good news, it landed on a "]) + str(randint(1,6)) + ".")


#emoji nuke
#@client.command()
#async def endmoji(bepis):
 #   for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 99999999999999999):
  #      await bepis.send(random.choice([":shit:",":zany_face:",":eggplant:",":money_with_wings:",":flag_de:",":hot_face:",":rofl:",":100:"]))

#bacon
@client.command(aliases=["yum"])
async def bacon(bepis):
    await bepis.send(":pig: :axe: :bacon: :fork_and_knife:")

#bruh
@client.command()
async def test(bepis):
    await bepis.send("test for no prefix")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should regenerate your API token, as it is still visible in the revision history.

Comment: Anyway, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try to make the question clear. Which command should have this behaviour? Why do you want it to have this behaviour? How much of this code is actually relevant to the problem? (And do we need to see a bunch of emoji meming and crude language in order to understand the problem?)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could think of to make the command "without the prefix" is with [**on_message**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.on_message), but if you don't have to I would suggest avoiding this because it could react to other messages not connected with the bot, you also have to enable **Intents.messages** on [Discord website](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and it might also confuse other people.

### Example command using on_message

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello command": #you can also use "if message.content.startswith():"
        await message.channel.send("Hello")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

[Startswith() method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith)

But if you still prefer making a command without prefix try to add as many conditions as you can (ex. only one channel where command can be used).

Comment: Another way would be to use get_prefix and return a prefix if the command doesn't startwith that specific command name otherwise just return an empty prefix